# Changing HTML tag attributes with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, label, placeholder, modernizr

I'm trying to get what I think is a really nice bit of HTML5 in my website - the placeholder attribute for `input` fields.

But the way I've got it in my website degrades badly. Because I've skipped labels for the fields and used the placeholder as its label.

At the moment I have several input fields with placeholders, they look like this:

```
<input placeholder="hereismyplaceholder" />
```

But where HTML5 placeholder support is not available, I would like all of the input fields with placeholders to change to this. Obviously with their equivalent placeholder text:

```
<input onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'hereismyplaceholder';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'hereismyplaceholder') {this.value = '';}" value="hereismyplaceholder" />
```

So I've pulled in [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/), and I'm getting it to detect the placeholders with the following javascript:

```
if (Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
} else {
// BUT I NEED SOMETHING IN HERE
}
```

But I have no idea what to do now. Because I have no experience with javascript, I'm not a developer.

The simplest solution would be the best please. I'm not fussed about good practice, I just want it to work for now.

Comment: From the HTML 5 specification: "The placeholder attribute should not be used as an alternative to a label.". Placeholder provides a hint to aid entry, it isn't a replacement for a real label.

Comment: Yep I've read that too. Thanks. General designer's move for the sake of clarity. It just simplifies things in my opinion. ie. Twitter

Comment: I'd say label-less fields can work when you have very few fields, maybe 2 or 3

Comment: Clarity is not achieved by removing the instructions just as someone is about to start filling in the field.

Comment: Wrong word then. And I do have very few fields. There's 2 with placeholders. 3 together on another page. And 1 together on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't ask for jQuery, but I didn't want to worry about cross-browser issues:

```
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
  $("input[type=text]")
  .focus(function(e){
      if (this.value == $(this).attr('placeholder')) {
         this.value = '';
      }         
  })
  .blur(function(e){
    setPlaceholder(this);
  }).each(function(index, el){
    setPlaceholder(el);
  });

  function setPlaceholder(el) {
    if (el.value  == '') {
        el.value = $(el).attr('placeholder');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume something similar to this would be achievable in regular javascript? Or are there big cross-browser issues and should I just put jQuery into my website to make this easy?

Comment: It is simple enough that there aren't too may cross browser issues here, it's easily achievable with regular JS, just more code. I cannot go ahead and write it all though. If you're not experienced with JS, I would include jQuery and start using it from now on. Makes things much easier (though I use something else myself)

Comment: "Didn't work" is the worst comment when asking for help. Did you debug? which part isn't working? I'm not going to write production ready code for you, I'm showing you how to do it!

Comment: My bad. From IE Dev Tools console:
`SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
javascript.js, line 6 character 5`
Probably now worth mentioning - it shouldn't matter that that jquery code is inside a linked javascript document, for the sake of tidyness, should it?

Comment: Ah, the minified version of jquery from their website doesn't work - http://code.jquery.com/jquerymin.js
Okay well, after using the normal version of jquery, that error's gone but there's still no placeholders

Comment: Like I said, I'm not going to write it all for you. If you look at the working link I posted, http://jsfiddle.net/SnQVE/2/ ,  you can go from there.

Comment: The minified version they've given a link for here: http://code.jquery.com/, it's worth mentioning, to make myself not look stupid. They've missed the . before min

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here, http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#input

For your specific use case, the code should be

```
// if placeholder isn't supported:
if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
  // use a input hint script
  setInputHint(document.getElementById('idoftheinputelement'),'hereismyplaceholder');
}
```

Comment: This requires you to have a separate call for each of the fields needed and you need to duplicate what you've already put into the placeholder HTML attribute